# Unable to find xpath using Appium desktop

Tags: selenium, xpath, appium, appium-desktop

**Use case**
I need to click on ANSWER button as shown in screen below

[image: Need to click on answer button]

**What I Tried ?**

I used Appium desktop to inspect element , but this Answer button does not seems to be effectively identified by it.

Having little experience in creating XPATH,  I tried with diffrent combinations of XPATH

```
//android.widget.FrameLayout[contains(@text,'ANSWER')]")
//android.widget.ScrollView[contains(@text,'ANSWER')]")  
//android.widget.Button[@resource-id='android:id/action0']
android:id/action0
xpath=//*[@text='ANSWER']
```

But none of them are working!!

Is there anyway of doing it ?

Comment: It looks like this element is not in the tree... you will need to use OCR or something...

Comment: Can you elaborate little bit more

Comment: alternatively try using uiautomatorviewer,

Comment: Try using AndroidUIAutomatorViewer to check for an alternate resource id that can be used in your code to identify the button. Thanks.

Comment: Is this button a system alert or part of your application?

Comment: Its native call answering part of a typical mobile phone UI!!